# Changing colour of material over time

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors

Is there a way to change the colour of a material over time? I want the background of my 2D game to change from white to red in a nice smooth transition.

In Unity 5, you can set the "Albedo" colour. This is the property I am looking to change. I can do this through using this:

```
back.SetColor("_Color", new Color(255, 0, 0, 0.5f));
```

However, how can the colour slowly change instead of being so instant?

Answer (score 0):

not tested but try it this way:

```
var threshold = 0.001f;
var speed = 5.0f;

function Start()
{
    // Execution
    StartCoroutine("ChangeToColor", new Color(1.0f, 0f, 0f));
}

IEnumerator ChangeToColor(Color newColor)
{
    var getColor = back.GetColor("_Color");
    while(((Vector4)getColor - (Vector4)newColor).magnitude < threshold)
    {
        back.SetColor("_Color", Vector4.Lerp(getColor, newColor, Time.deltaTime * speed));
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm im not the best with js but try that