# cant set material in UI text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change my text color after sometime and want to continue the process. I was trying to do that by changing the material color.but the text gets filled up when I am trying to add a material on it. here's the image which will help you to understand.The first one is without a material and the second one is with a material.
[image]

[image]

Comment: UI materials don't work like regular materials. You've gone and [XY Problem'd](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) yourself.

Comment: so can you please tell me how to solve the material problem for UI? @draco

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211837/changing-colour-of-material-over-time Albeit you'd be targetting the `textObj.color` instead of a `materialObj.color`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a user defined material for the UI. The reason you see a blcock shaped image instead of your Text is because of the shader of the Material. You cannot use the Standard shader or any shader not intended to be used for the UI. *You must use the shader under the UI shader menu*.

Select your scoreMat Material and change its shader to *UI* ---> *Default* shader.

[image]